# sort pairwise shortest distance

Tags: matlab, shortest

This is my problem.

```
clc; clear all; close all;  
N = 10;
R = randn(N,1)+10;R(end) = R(1);
tht = linspace(0,2*pi,N).';
x = R.*cos(tht);
y = R.*sin(tht);
plot(x, y,'o-b');
```

Randomly sorting the arrays

```
X = x(randperm(size(x,1)),:);
Y = y(randperm(size(y,1)),:);
hold on, plot(X,Y,'o-r');
```

As it can be seen the contour that is drawn has overlapping regions. so I wanted to draw a non-overlapping closed contour. One idea that I got was by ordering the elements of the matrix such that the adjacent distances between the elements of the matrix are minimum. So the closest points will be adjacent to one another.

Can anyone specify how I can do it ? I tried to use pdist2 but failed.

Comment: Have you tried using `contour`?

Comment: So if I understand you correctly, you want to re-order some vertices such that they are ordered in a (counter)clockwise fashion, as seen by the geometric center of the contour?

Comment: @MarcClaesen: Example?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to reorder some vertices such that all the lines drawn between subsequent points form a closed, non-overlapping contour.

This can be accomplished by re-ordering your vertices in a (counter)clockwise fashion about the centre of mass of all the points. In 2D, this can most easily be accomplished by sorting the output of [`atan2`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/atan2.html):

```
%// Compute centre of mass
r_COM = sum([X, Y]) / numel(X);

%// Sort all vertices by angle
[~, I] = sort(atan2(Y - r_COM(2), X - r_COM(1)));

%// Plot the new contour
hold on, plot(X([I; I(1)]),Y([I; I(1)]), '.-k', 'linewidth', 2);
```

Results:

[image: results]

Comment: @EitanT: thanks; since I installed [Amro's userscript to properly highlight MATLAB code on SO](https://github.com/amroamroamro/prettify-matlab/raw/master/js/prettify-matlab.user.js) I always forget those slashes (`%//`)

Comment: No problem. And congrats, you are eligible for the MATLAB gold badge ;)

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis you my dear Sir is a genius!! Hat's off to you!!

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis Hi again could you clarify the procedure for convex and concave polygons ? will the answers differ ?

Comment: @roni: there are valid concave polygons that do not self-intersect  but for which the vertices are **not** all ordered (counter)clockwise. So my solution works for *all* convex, and *most* concave non-self-intersecting polygons.

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis can I use the sorting matrix I to sort another array with the same sorting order ??

Comment: @roni: ...asking the same question twice will not double the chance I will understand :)

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis sorry about that. Actually what i wanted was that whether I could use the matrix I as the sorting order for any other matrix whose size is same as that of X or Y. But never mind I got it. Thanks for your help.